# .Net Core How to Automatically generate ID when importing Data from Excel into Database?

Tags: asp.net-core, import-from-excel

I am using EF core. I was able to import data from Excel into the Database. But how should I do so that when entering data, the ID will automatically increase according to the amount of data instead of having to enter it in Excel? Can you tell me about the solution?

I can't find any documentation or examples about this.

This is the code that I am using to Import data from Excel
[Here](https://paste.mod.gg/segicezeqa.csharp)

Comment: What database? Almost all database products have an auto-incrementing column type or function that's used to generate unique IDs for rows

Comment: BTW EF Core is a bad choice here. It's meant to map between objects and tables and can't handle large inserrts. There are no objects in this case, only Excel rows. You could use a library like ExcelDataReader to read the Excel file and send the data directly to the server using whatever bulk insert mechanism is available. Eg in SQL Server you can use SqlBulkCopy. MySql clients have their own MySqlBulkCopy

Comment: PS your code doesn't use EF Core at all. It uses ADO.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was typing this on comment... but the code kind of ugly, so here is the idea.

Since we use Datatable under the hood then using SqlBulk to import data, why not re-assign the Id column with your desire key as needed ?

```
var myTable = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
    {
        row["Id"] = Guid.NewGuid(); // just assign any key here
    }
```